# Spring-boot service not starting as Eureka discovery client in java 11

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, java-11, service-discovery

> We using java 11(amazon corretto) in our application,
>    we have 2 spring boot services eureka server and client, server getting up without having problem but client service not starting as eureka discovery client throws error InvocationTargetException
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SERVER_SENT_EVENTS_TYPE when trying to start .
>   But as a standalone service it is getting started without exception.

I have tried with below dependencies 
pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jcifs/jcifs -> SMB location -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-spring-boot-starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-multipart-provider -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I have added blow dependency for java 11 support :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

server application.yml

```
spring :
  application :
    name : eureka-naming-server

server:
  port : ${PORT:8761}

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

client application.yml

```
...
...
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
    lease:
      duration: 5
```

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ClientApplication implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        SpringApplication.run(ClientApplication.class, args);
    }

@Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;

    }
}
```

Please find the log here :

```
2019-09-11 20:19:45.730  INFO 8720 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
2019-09-11 20:19:45.730  INFO 8720 --- [           main] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2019-09-11 20:19:45.730  INFO 8720 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1568213385730 with initial instances count: 0
2019-09-11 20:19:45.730  INFO 8720 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application Client with eureka with status UP
2019-09-11 20:19:45.730  INFO 8720 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1568213385730, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2019-09-11 20:19:45.730  INFO 8720 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_Client/localhost:Client:8083: registering service...
2019-09-11 20:19:45.802  INFO 8720 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_Client/localhost:Client:8083 - registration status: 204
2019-09-11 20:19:45.805  INFO 8720 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-09-11 20:19:45.805  INFO 8720 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Unregistering application Client with eureka with status DOWN
2019-09-11 20:19:45.806  WARN 8720 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1568213385806, current=DOWN, previous=UP]
2019-09-11 20:19:45.806  INFO 8720 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_Client/localhost:Client:8083: registering service...
2019-09-11 20:19:45.815  INFO 8720 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-09-11 20:19:45.818  INFO 8720 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_Client/localhost:Client:8083 - registration status: 204
2019-09-11 20:19:45.818  INFO 8720 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2019-09-11 20:19:48.833  INFO 8720 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Unregistering ...
2019-09-11 20:19:48.857  INFO 8720 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_Client/localhost:Client:8083 - deregister  status: 200
2019-09-11 20:19:48.873  INFO 8720 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient
2019-09-11 20:19:48.889 ERROR 8720 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SERVER_SENT_EVENTS_TYPE
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.isSseResourceMethod(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:162) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.6.3.Final.jar:3.6.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.<init>(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:147) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.6.3.Final.jar:3.6.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.processMethod(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:349) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.6.3.Final.jar:3.6.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.register(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:276) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.6.3.Final.jar:3.6.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:227) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.6.3.Final.jar:3.6.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:199) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.6.3.Final.jar:3.6.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:185) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.6.3.Final.jar:3.6.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessor.onApplicationEvent(SpringBeanProcessor.java:530) ~[resteasy-spring-3.7.0.Final.jar:3.7.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:402) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:896) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.demo.Client.ClientApplication.main(ClientApplication.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:542) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:542)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SERVER_SENT_EVENTS_TYPE
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.isSseResourceMethod(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:162)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.<init>(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:147)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.processMethod(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:349)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.register(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:276)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:227)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:199)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:185)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessor.onApplicationEvent(SpringBeanProcessor.java:530)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:402)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:896)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at com.demo.Client.ClientApplication.main(ClientApplication.java:36)
    ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.780 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-11T20:19:48+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 55M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project Client: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: SERVER_SENT_EVENTS_TYPE -> [Help 1]
```

> I expect client gets registered with eureka server in java 11(amazon corretto).

Thanks in advance

Comment: pleases post the full exception.

Comment: @spencergibb Please see the updated question.

Comment: @WinKey This issue is caused by incompatible version of dependencies. `resteasy-spring-boot-starter` will add all the correct version of resteasy dependencies, you should not override them in your pom.xml. So removing any version that is added by the starter will likely solve the problem. (ex. `resteasy-spring-3.7.0` should use `resteasy-jaxrs-3.7.0`, not 3.6.3)

Comment: @helospark That worked, There was a jar conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the below dependency in the discovery server.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```